# how to get name of file using Index of command in java

Tags: java, jsp

```
public class myclass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String filepath = "E:\\SW\\eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32\\eclipse\\CBDTFiles\\Circulars\\CBDTLaws\\HTMLFiles\\file1.htm";
        String w=filepath.replace("E:\\SW\\eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32\\eclipse\\CBDTFiles\\Circulars\\CBDTLaws\\HTMLFiles\\", "");
        System.out.println(w);

    }

}
```

This is My code i am able to display file name using replace of command But i want to get file Using Index of command how i will get Index of HTMLFiles  from that we can get file name because file is comingDynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#lastIndexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) with [`String#substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29):

```
String fileName = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you insisting on `indexOf()`? The correct way is `new File(filepath).getName().`